# Presenting an EKCalendarChooser modally

Tags: ios

I'm trying to present the new EKCalendarChooser in my app as a modal view. I'm doing it using the following code:

```
EKCalendarChooser *calendarChooser = [[EKCalendarChooser alloc] 
    initWithSelectionStyle:EKCalendarChooserSelectionStyleMultiple 
     displayStyle:EKCalendarChooserDisplayAllCalendars
     eventStore:self.ekDataSource.eventStore];


calendarChooser.showsDoneButton = YES;
calendarChooser.showsCancelButton = NO;
calendarChooser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
calendarChooser.delegate = self;

[[self navigationController] presentViewController:calendarChooser animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem I'm having is that when the view is displayed, it is missing the done button. If however, I display the view using the following code:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:calendarChooser animated:YES];
```

It works just fine. The done button is displayed. Shouldn't the done button be shown with the **presentViewController** call as well?

Thanks in advance for any help!

pmb

Answer (score 0):

If your current view controller is inside a navigation controller, then you should continue to use that navigation controller, unless you really need more screen space.  You should then use an animation to present the new view controller, modally, which tells the user that they are leaving the context of navigation controller.

[self.navigationController pushViewControllerAnimated:how];

Answer (score 0):

Use the EKClaenderChooserDelegate method.Using this method i resolved my issue

- (void)calendarChooserDidFinish:(EKCalendarChooser *)calendarChooser

  {
      [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  }